# Pythonにてログイン機能付サイトでrequestsする方法

Tags: python, python3, python-requests

下記のログイン機能付サイトでrequestを使ってログインしたいですが、
うまくログイン出来ないです。
python seleniumだとうまくログインできますが、
下記のコードrequestだとうまく行かず、ログインボタンのところが引っかかります。。
requestでログイン可能でしょうか。

※こちらのサイト参考にしました。
[ログイン機能付サイトでスクレイピング【requests】【BeautifulSoup】](https://qiita.com/syunyo/items/36af8bcb501baf8c7014)

[ログイン出来ないサイト userlocal](https://auth.userlocal.jp/)

code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import urllib3
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning 
urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning, module='bs4')
import io

# メールアドレスとパスワードの指定
USER = "example@gmial.com"
PASS = "1234567"

# セッションを開始
session = requests.session()

# ログイン
login_info = {
    "email":USER,
    "password":PASS,
    "commit":"ログイン"
}

# action
url_login = "https://social-admin.userlocal.jp/accounts"
res = session.post(url_login, data=login_info,verify=False)
res.raise_for_status()

print(res.text)
```

エラー内容

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/example/Documents/example/example.py", line 31, in <module>
    res.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Users\example\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 941, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 422 Client Error: Unprocessable Entity for url: https://social-admin.userlocal.jp/accounts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ブラウザの開発者ツールでリクエストを見てみると次のことがわかります。

1. POSTするURLは`https://auth.userlocal.jp/login`
2. POSTするデータには`authenticity_token`が含まれる

`authenticity_token`は例えば次のようにすれば手に入るはずです。

```
url_accounts = "https://social-admin.userlocal.jp/accounts"
res = session.get(url_accounts)

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
auth_token = soup.find('input', {'name': 'authenticity_token'}).get('value')
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。上記の`authenticity_token`をヒントにし又、下記のURLを参考にしながらrequestでログイン出来ました。
https://qiita.com/fake_engineer_00/items/82c3f63ccb6416fd5fca